# Why the Gaussian wavepacket only spreads in the free Schrodinger equation? It doesn't spread in the case where you have a harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Why the Gaussian wavepacket only spreads in the free Schrodinger equation? It doesn't spread in the case where you have a harmonic oscillator. How to prove the situation in a harmonic oscillator?
Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/harmosc.pdf these notes give a good description of why wavepackets don't spread out for a harmonic oscillator. Specifically the part about "coherent states". I don't have a good intuitive answer to the question so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: You can ask this same question about other waves too: why do waves on a guitar string oscillate in place while waves on the ocean seem to spread forever? The general answer: different boundary conditions and potential energy landscapes lead to different dynamics

Comment: A bit more specific answer: Water waves spread out forever on a flat ocean, but do not in a bowl with sides shaped like a parabola.

Comment: Momentum conservation. A bound state does not conserve momentum. It doesn't do that in classical physics, either, as the mentioned example of a guitar string shows. The difference is that in classical mechanics we know the system that absorbs the momentum change of the string: it's the guitar body. In highly trivialized versions of quantum mechanical problems we simply assume that there is such a system, but we neglect to characterize it physically.

Comment: @benrg, Dear benrg, the question was reopened. Thank you for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Straightforward approach (Schrödinger picture)**
Oscillator eigenfunctions form a full basis:
$$
H\phi_n(x)=\epsilon_n\phi_n(x)$$
The straightforward solution would be to expand the initial wave packet in terms of this basis and then account for their time evolution:
$$
\psi(x,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n\phi_n(x),c_n=\int dx \psi(x)^*\phi_n(x);$$
then
$$\psi(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_ne^{-\frac{i\epsilon_n t}{\hbar}}\phi_n(x).$$
Resumming the series might not be straighforward (or it might), but one can calculate the characteristics of this packet - like the position of its center, $\langle x(t)\rangle$, its width, $\sigma^2(t)=\langle x^2(t)\rangle -\langle x(t)\rangle^2$, etc.

> Why the Gaussian wavepacket *only* spreads in the free Schrodinger equation?
> (emphasis mine)

*Only* is misleading here: harmonic oscillator is the only case where the packet does not spread. We could first note that for propagating states, like free Schrödinger equation, the spread is a consequence of *dispersion* - wave of different frequency have different velocities. In oscillator all states evolve periodically and with *commensurate* frequencies. The worst that one could expect for a wave packet in such a case is to undergo collapse-and-revival with the period of oscillator. A Gaussian packet is the one that doesn't do even that.

**Remark:** this might be not the easiest approach (in terms of time and calculations), but it is foolproof and a good exercise for some basic notions about Hilbert space and quantum mechanics.

**Faster approach (Heisenberg picture)**
As a faster approach one could solve only for the mean position and its standard deviation. We have Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega_0^2x^2}{2}.$$ In Heisenberg picture (i.e., where the time evolution is encoded in the operators) we have *operator* equations
$$\dot{x}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}[x,H]=\frac{p}{m},
\dot{p}\frac{1}{i\hbar}[p,H]=-m\omega^2x,$$
that is the position operator satisfies
$$
\ddot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2x(t)=0,$$
with the solution in terms of the operators at time $t=0$ given by
$$x(t)=x(0)\cos(\omega_0t)+\frac{p(0)}{m\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0t),$$
where the action of operators $x(0),p(0)$ on the *initial* wave function is, as usual, multiplication by $x$ and $p(0)=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$.

Let us now take a Gaussian wave packet (for simplicity I take a packet with zero initial momentum):
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4\sigma^2}}.$$
It is easy to calculate that
$$\langle x(0)\rangle = \int dx x|\psi(x)|^2=x_0,\langle p(0)\rangle=\int dx \psi(x)^*p(0)\psi(x)=0\\\Rightarrow
\langle x(t)\rangle=x_0\cos(\omega_0t).$$

We can also calculate
$$
\langle x^2(t)\rangle = \langle x^2(0)\rangle\cos^2(\omega_0t)+
\frac{\langle p^2(0)\rangle}{m^2\omega_0^2}\sin^2(\omega_0t)+
\frac{\langle x(0)p(0)\rangle+\langle p(0)x(0)\rangle}{m\omega_0}\cos(\omega_0t)\sin(\omega_0t)
$$
One can easily calculate that
$$
\langle x^2(0)\rangle=x_0^2+\sigma^2,\langle p^2(0)\rangle=\frac{\hbar^2}{4\sigma^2},\langle x(0)p(0)\rangle=\langle p(0)x(0)\rangle^*=\frac{i\hbar}{2}.$$
Therefore
$$
\langle x^2(t)\rangle-\langle x(t)\rangle^2=
\sigma^2\cos^2(\omega_0t)+\frac{\hbar^2}{4m^2\omega_0^2\sigma^2}\sin^2(\omega_0t),
$$
that is the wave packet is *breathing* with a doubled frequency $2\omega_0$ (since $2\cos^2(x)=1+\cos(2x), 2\sin^2(x)=1-\cos(2x)$.)
However we can write
$$
\langle x^2(t)\rangle-\langle x(t)\rangle^2=
\sigma^2+\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{4m^2\omega_0^2\sigma^2}-\sigma^2\right)\sin^2(\omega_0t),
$$
which means that the width of the packet would remain constant, if it has value
$$
\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_0}}.$$

**Ad-hoc approach**
In principle, we could directly define the coherent state as *a state that does not spread with time*, i.e., a Gaussian state with the width obtained above. A more conventional definition (which will be useful when one tackles second quantization and path integrals) is to define coherent states as eigenstates of the lowering operator.

Oscillator Hamiltonian can be written as
$$
H=\hbar\omega_0\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
where
$$
a=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega_0}{2\hbar}}x+\frac{ip}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega_0}},
a^\dagger=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega_0}{2\hbar}}x-\frac{ip}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega_0}}.
$$
The operators $a,a^\dagger$ are called *lowering and rasing* operators, as their action on the eigenstates of the oscillator Hamilronian is
$$
H|n\rangle=\hbar\omega_0\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)|n\rangle=\epsilon_n|n\rangle,\\
a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle,a^\dagger|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle.
$$
It is easy to find the eigenfunctions of lowering operator
$$a\psi_\lambda(x)=\lambda\psi_\lambda(x)\Rightarrow 
\psi_\lambda(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4\sigma^2}},\\
\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega_0}{2\hbar}}x_0,\sigma^2=\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_0}$$

In Heisenberg picture the evolution of these operators is given by $$
a(t)=a(0)e^{-i\omega_0t},a^\dagger(t)=a^\dagger(0)e^{-i\omega_0t}.$$
Expressing the position operator in terms of these operators, we have
$$
x(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_0}}\left[a(t)+a^\dagger(t)\right],
$$
we can now calculate the averages $\langle \psi_\lambda |x(t)|\psi_\lambda\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_\lambda |x^2(t)|\psi_\lambda\rangle$, using that
$$
a(0)|\psi_\lambda\rangle=\lambda |\psi_\lambda\rangle,\langle \psi_\lambda|a^\dagger(0)=\langle \psi_\lambda|\lambda, \text{ and }aa^\dagger-a^\dagger a=1.
$$
We will obtain that
$$
\langle \psi_\lambda |x(t)|\psi_\lambda\rangle=x_0\cos(\omega_0t),\\
\langle \psi_\lambda |x^2(t)|\psi_\lambda\rangle-
\langle \psi_\lambda |x(t)|\psi_\lambda\rangle^2=\sigma^2.
$$

Comment: A general Gaussian wave packet does also "breath" in a harmonic potential as it propagates. It does retain at all time a functional form of a Gaussian but the width parameter is not constant, it spreads and contracts periodically. Only a coherent Gaussian wave packet does not spread at all. But one thing that is true for all Gaussian wave packets in a harmonic potential is that the center follows a classical trajectory.

Comment: @HansWurst Dear Hans, Yes, your statement is consistent with the literature. I want to know what is coherent Gaussian wave packet ？ and The width is maximum at the center or at the edge? thank you!

Comment: @Ironman1965 A coherent Gaussian wave packet has the same constant width, at all times, as it propagates in a harmonic potential. The very first comment to your question by user AXensen links to a file that describes the mathematical properties of a coherent Gaussian state. The wikipedia page for [Coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state) shows an animation of a coherent Gaussian wave packet.

Comment: @Ironman1965 *coherent state* is an eigenstate of the annihilation/lowering operator - if one uses this ansatz, it is easy to show that it conserves width.

Comment: @Ironman1965 see the expanded answer.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a small mistake in your derivation: $\langle x(0)p(0)\rangle={i\hbar\over 2}$.

Comment: @Christophe thanks. I was a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not true. Not every gaussian remains "unspread" in a harmonic potential, only the one with a very specific width determined by the mass of the particle and curvature of the potential.

If you narrow down the question to why does that specific gaussian remain "intact" in a harmonic potential as time goes on, the answer is that because it corresponds to certain (0th) eigenstate of the system in question.

It is a general fact in QM that eigenstates correspond to the so-called stationary states, i.e. they only acquire phase as time goes on. If your function happens to match one of the eigenstate wavefunctions, it will retain its form indefinitely, otherwise it will spread out.

In your specific example, a (specially chosen) gaussian happens to the eigenstate for a simple harmonic oscillator, hence it will remain as is. For a free particle, eigenstate wavefunctions are free exponentials of the form $\psi(x) = \exp(- i p x /\hbar)$ and not gaussians, therefore gaussian will spread here. Conversely, a profile of the form $\exp(- i p x /\hbar)$ would remain intact in the absence of potential and would fall apart under harmonic potential.

“Whose image is this? And whose inscription?”

“Caesar’s,”

“Give back to Caesar what is Caesar’s"